# How to have an undefined amount of captures in a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, capture-group

I'm making a simple stack-based language which uses *commands* to manipulate the stack. When I find a command in the source, I use this regex to separate out the actual command name, such as *sum*, and the arguments to the command. Arguments are surrounded by triangle brackets and are separated by commas.

Here's the regex I'm currently using:

```
(?<command>[^<>\s]+)(\<(?<args>(\d+)+(?>,\s*\d+)*)\>)?
```

Now this works fine, and here are some examples of it working:

```
+              => command: '+', args: nil
sum<5>         => command: 'sum', args: '5'
print<1, 2, 3> => command: 'print', args: '1, 2, 3'
```

This works exactly as I want for each one but the last. My question is, is there a way to capture each argument separately? I mean like this:

```
print<1, 2, 3> => command: 'print', args: ['1', '2', '3']
```

By the way, I'm using the latest Ruby regex engine.

Comment: No, using a simple regex with repeated capturing groups will not work that way. You need to split the second capture with `,` as a post-process step. Ruby regex engine does not keep the capture stack.

Comment: That's a shame - thanks, anyway

Comment: Very few regex flavors have capture group stack support, only .NET and Python PyPi regex module support them by default. A close pattern would be [`/(?:\G(?!\A),\s*|(?<command>[^<>\s]+)<)(?<args>\d+)/`](http://rubular.com/r/BDocFayOkZ) but it uses multiple matching, and if you have more than one occurrences in the input, you might have trouble delimiting them.

Comment: I tried that out on `print<1, 2, 3>` and the _args_ capture was just '1' - it's fine, anyway - i'm just going to use the splitting thing you mentioned before

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why answer in the comments? I would have upvoted you.

Comment: @Max, I like to post when I have a good solution on hands, now I only have http://ideone.com/fbmnOt and have little time to enhance it.

Comment: @Max: Now, posted, when the kids have gone to bed, I could try my hand at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get such an output using a simple regex with repeated capturing groups in Ruby regex as the engine does not keep the capture stack.

You need to split the second capture with `,` as a post-process step.

See [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/orGNBm):

```
def cmd_split(s)
    rx = /(?<command>[^<>\s]+)(<(?<args>(\d+)+(?:,\s*\d+)*)>)?/
    res = []
    s.scan(rx) { 
        res << ($~[:args] != nil ? 
            Hash["command", $~[:command], "args", $~[:args].split(/,\s*/)] : 
            Hash[$~[:command], ""]) }
    return res
end

puts cmd_split("print<1, 2, 3>") # => {"command"=>"print", "args"=>["1", "2", "3"]}
puts cmd_split("disp<1>")        # => {"command"=>"disp", "args"=>["1"]}
puts cmd_split("+")              # => {"+"=>""}
```